# Excel XLookUp with single critera but multiple columns

Tags: excel-formula, xlookup

XLookup is capable of doing look-ups with multiple criteria using two methods, concatenation and another boolean array.  Both are pretty straightforward and easy to use.  I prefer the boolean array method and have used it a few times.

Most examples you find online will show something like this.  You have a table of items, with the following columns. Item, Size, Color & Price.  The look-up is then done by finding a Price based upon an item that matches a given Item,Size,Color combination as shown in this image.

[image]

I'm looking for a solution that allows for this.  Given the example above, let's say we have striped items, so we have two colors, Color and Color2.

I'm looking to now match Item="Hoodie" AND Size="Medium" AND (Color="Blue" OR Color2="Blue")

Is this possible?  The XLookup boolean array is doing a Bitwise AND comparison but I need a Bitwise OR.

Comment: Perhaps consider index() with match() and have 2 matches to get the two colors.

Comment: `OR` use `+` make sure to use the appropriate `()` to isolate. IE: `(B5:B15=H5)*(C5:C15=H6)*((D5:D15=H7)+(E5:E15=H7))`

Comment: Would the colors have separate columns, or are they separated by a delimiter/space within a cell? Better to post data per your situation. You could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to edit data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, just doing 2 columns for colors:

```
IFERROR(MATCH(D2,A3:A5,0),MATCH(D2,B3:B5,0))
```

Note, another iferror() is needed if the target color does not exist in either column, but that depends how you want index() to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer by experimenting with different operators.  What I found was that this function here.

[image]

To break down this function we have the following.

=XLOOKUP(1,(B5:B15=I5)*(C5:C15=I6)*((D5:D15=I7)**+**(E5:E15=I7)),F5:F15)

You can see we search 4 different arrays for 3 values. It's important to note that the last two arrays we search are enclosed in their own set of parenthesis and that the last two array searches are joined with a + character and not the * character.  This results in an XOR join, instead of an XAND join.

So the logic could be written as this.
Find an item where
Item = "Hoodie" AND Size = "Large" AND (Color = "Blue" OR Color2 = "Blue")